# Jquery variable.addClass()

Tags: javascript, jquery

In a jquery function, I create a variable to hold the name of an image:

```
    tickNumber = $(this).data('imagenumber');
    tickName = "tick" + tickNumber;
```

This generates "tick1", "tick2" etc.. I want to be able to change the class of the image with the name stored in that variable, I'm not sure how though. This is what I'm doing now:

```
        tickName.removeClass('visible');
        tickName.addClass('hidden')
```

That doesn't work, I'm not sure how I'm suppose to do it. Also, tickName is correct, doing this works:

```
        $(tick1).removeClass('visible');
        $(tick1).addClass('hidden');
```

But I  need to use the variable's name instead.

Comment: tickName will be a `id` or `class` ? e.g. ` <img id='thisIsID' class='thisIsClass' .. />` ?

Comment: You could use `$(eval(tickName))` to get the variable with the name that's in `tickName` **but** you really should restructure your code to something less nasty than `eval`

Comment: if tickName is an id or class you can get the element by doing this for class  $('.'+tickName) and this for id : $('#'+tickName)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If **tickName** is used as ID then use it like

```
$("#" + tickName).removeClass('visible');
$("#" + tickName).addClass('hidden');
```

Else if it's a CLASS use:

```
$("." + tickName).removeClass('visible');
$("." + tickName).addClass('hidden');
```

Comment: And if it's a name use: `$("[name=” + tickName + ”]");`

Answer (score 2):

Make `tickName` itself a jQuery object by wrapping in `$(...)`

```
$('.'+tickName).removeClass('visible');
$('.'+tickName).addClass('hidden');
```

and add a `.` to target classes

Comment: This will try to select an HTML tag called `tick1` [or class, with the dot]; based on the code in the question `tick1` is the name of a variable, not the tag

Comment: @blgt, I know, I just read his question and realized he was targeting classes